# Correct entry range vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a record but it gives an error

```
Set range5 = sht3.Range("B" + fcell.Row + 1 + ":D" + lLastRow2)

fcell is Find = 30
lLastRow2 = 31
```

I want to write in one line

```
Set range5 = sht3.Range("B31:D31")
```

`fcell` and `lLastRow2` these are dynamic values

Comment: `&` versus `+` for VBA

Comment: `sht3.Range("B" & fcell.Row + 1 & ":D" & lLastRow2)`. What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about concatenating:

```
Set range5 = sh3.Range("B" & fcell.Row + 1 & ":D" & lLastRow2)
```

Comment: I can’t thank you enough!